# Radius size in decimal degrees of the current map zoom level using Google Maps Android API v2

Tags: android, google-maps

I am currently developing an android project which needs to place on a map (created from Google Maps Android API v2) markers for every place which is currently positioned in the map field of view.

I'm using a database on a windows azure server and I'm obtaining all the records that have the latitude and longitude inside a circle with origin in device location and the radius being the distance for the center to a corner/side of the phone.

How can I obtain the distance for the center of the map to a side? And how to convert it into decimal degrees?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fetch the LatLngBounds from the Map

```
LatLngBounds bounds = mMap.getProjection().getVisibleRegion().latLngBounds;
```

Using the `northeast` and the `southwest` corner of the bound you should be able to query your DB to only select the markers you're interested in.

You can also check if a marker is within that LatLngBounds

```
bounds.contains(yourLatLngFromAzure)
```

yourLatLngFromAzure is a `com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng`

Comment: I think he needs the visible area to query the database in the first place

Comment: Thanks. It seems like a good idea to search if the objects are in the "bounds". But I created a custom API on server for GET method and I'm sending the device coordinates and the radius around it. I'll try to use bounds.northeast and bounds.southwest and the Location.distanceBetween()/2 to obtain the radius. I might have to do a convertion in decimal degrees. Thanks again.

Comment: The following library project also contains a lot of handy functions (including a distanceBetween LatLng objects) https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/blob/master/library/src/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.java

Comment: Job done using the LatLngBounds object just like @ddewaele suggested. I obtained the .norteast and .southwest LatLng point and divided the distance between them by 2, to obtain the screen (big) radius. Thanks 4 the assist!